# How can I input data into this web page from an excel/google sheet?

Tags: automation

I'm a teacher and I.T. student.

I have to input the students grades into this web page. Is there a way to automate this where the script matches the names on the sheet and on the web page and inserts the grades in the correct place?

They are in the same order, but in the web page, students who were transfered or changed classrooms appear, but the box can't be filled (as showed in the image).

I have a grasp that every row have an id, but i lack the knowledge to to know how to link the things.

I'm linking some images of the code and how it appears to me as a user.

My question is: what technology I can use to automate the process and make my job easier? I'm looking for a step-by-step guide (if it exists) or a guidance on what to study to make this project works.

If there is another topic answering this question, please link me.

Thanks.

Hoping for answers.
The web page look (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT2wd.png)
The tag the holds students names(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uiqum.png)
The tag the holds students gades(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQGJZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Selenium to locate the web element, import Excel file and then input data from Excel file to said element.

Locate element: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/

Insert value to element: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/interactions/

You can easily import Excel file in Python with Pandas (https://pythonbasics.org/read-excel/). As for other languages, I'm sure you can find some libraries with the same purpose.